# Como filtrar el dia de hoy en mysql con un campo timestamp?

Tags: mysql

Intente esto pero no me funciona, también intente con <> pero de igual forma no me funciona, mi tabla se llama visitas y el campo fecha de tipo timestamp:

```
$dia = date("Y-m-d");

$hora_min = $dia . ' 00:00:00';
$hora_max = $dia . ' 23:59:59' ;
$result = "SELECT * FROM visitas WHERE (fecha BETWEEN '$hora_min' AND '$hora_max')";


$result = $conexion->prepare($result);


$result->execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Saludos puedes intentar algo como esto en tu query:

```
SELECT * FROM visitas WHERE CURRENT_DATE() = date(fecha)
```

**Explicación**

Lo que hace [CURRENT_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_current_date.asp) es retornar la fecha actual , bien dado que en tu campo "**fecha**" es tipo **datetime** solo deseo retornar la parte de la fecha mas no las horas, minutos, segundos y esto lo logro con **date**.

Sabiendo todo esto puedo hacer en un where que me retorne mis registros del dia de hoy .

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp), así por ejemplo:

```
$dia = date("Y-m-d");
$hora_min = $dia . ' 00:00:00';
$hora_max = $dia . ' 23:59:59' ;

$result = "SELECT * 
           FROM visitas 
           WHERE (fecha BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$hora_min') 
                        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$hora_max'))";
$result = $conexion->prepare($result);
$result->execute();
```